# Authentication failure: su slower than sudo

Tags: sudo, authentication, su

I tried causing an `authentication-failure` error, once with `sudo` then with `su` and found out that `su` takes almost double the time (I launch that command and press `Enter` immediatly; with `sudo` I press `ctr-d` at the second password request).

```
usagi ~$ time su -c ls -l
Password: 
su: Authentication failure

real    0m5.410s
user    0m0.033s
sys     0m0.000s
usagi ~$ time sudo ls -l
[sudo] password for usagi: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for usagi: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt

real    0m2.718s
user    0m0.029s
sys     0m0.010s
```

What causes this gap?

P.S. If authentication is successful, both take the same time to execute the command.

Comment: It's quite possible that both commands have a built-in delay after incorrect authentication, and that the duration is different.

Comment: I tried this on Arch, but on Mint both takes ~2.5s to execute.
Is it possible that different distros have different commands?